# Retrieving Error messages from SWI-Prolog using java and jpl

Tags: java, swi-prolog, jpl

When I use JPL (from JavaSE 1.8), Prolog (SWI-Prolog version 8.2.4) it return an error message . E.g. when using consult and the file has errors:

```
ERROR: c:/program files/swipl/library/jpl.pl:5428:
ERROR:    '$open_shared_object'/3: The specified module could not be found.

ERROR: c:/program files/swipl/library/jpl.pl:5428:
ERROR:    c:/program files/swipl/library/jpl.pl:5428: Initialization goal raised exception:
ERROR:    jpl:jpl_get_default_jvm_opts/1: Unknown procedure: jpl:jni_get_default_jvm_opts/1
ERROR: c:/users/kt356/onedrive/desktop/system/medical expert system.pl:4:
ERROR:    Exported procedure jpl:jpl_c_lib_version/1 is not defined
```

What can I do so that to resolve this error?